# Timed scrolling in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, scroll

I need a script that scrolls automatically throught my page without buttons,I want it to scroll down every 10 seconds and then return to the top when done,how would i do this in javascript?

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a combination of the jquery [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)() plugin and the javascript [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)() function.  You would do something like (pseudocode):

```
setTimeout(scrollMyPage, 10000)
{
    if (At bottom of the page)
    {
        scroll To Top
    }
    else
    {
        scroll down the height of the browser window/a page
    }
}
```